# /dev/disk/by-id creating wrong symlinks for harddrive

Tags: hard-disk, udev

I'm running into an interesting problem where on reboots and power cycles, my harddrives will occasionally be given the wrong symlink in /dev/disk/by-id. For example, when I issue `ls /dev/disk/by-id` I expect the list to look something like:

```
ata-ST3000DM001-1CH166_W1F26HKK
ata-ST3000DM001-1CH166_Z1F2FBBY
```

But instead I see:

```
ata-ST3000DM001-1CH166_W1F26HKK
scsi-35000c500668a9bdb
```

The drive is still completely functional and is assigned a drive letter, but it gets labeled with that scsi name instead of the ata one. I've looked through dmesg and enabled extra logging in the kernel, but nothing has shed any light on what the issue could be. Any ideas on why the drive would be labeled improperly?

The distro is based off Debian 7.5 w/ kernel 3.2.45 and udev 173.

I've tried issuing `udevadm trigger` to refresh the by-id listings, but that doesn't seem to rectify the problem, is that information cached somewhere?